# running ffmpeg with nvenc inside nvidia docker

Tags: docker, ffmpeg, nvidia, nvidia-docker, nvenc

I  installed **Nvidia Video Codec SDK 8.2 + ffmpeg** inside a **docker container by using nvidia-docker** but when I run this

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -s:v 1920x1080 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -i HeavyHand_1080p.yuv -c:v h264_nvenc -preset slow -cq 10 -bf 2 -g 150 output.mp4
```

I got this **error**

> **Cannot load libnvidia-encode.so.1**
>
> **The minimum required Nvidia driver for nvenc is 390.25 or newer
>   Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder
>   for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate,
>   rate, width or height**

Otherwise **nvidia-smi** displays this

[image]

this gpu used is **GeForce 1050 Ti** and **the cuda version is 9.0**

Comment: Maybe tweak the ffmpeg code to tell you what version it *thinks* it is...

Answer (score 11):

When running inside a Docker container, by default not all of Nvidia libraries are mounted inside the container. Read more [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-container-runtime#nvidia_driver_capabilities) and [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/user-guide.html#environment-variables-oci-spec).
You can see all libraries available in your Docker container by running this: `ldconfig -p | grep -E 'libcuda|libnvidia'`

To fix this, you should modify the `NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES` environment variable in your Docker image. For example, you can append `ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=all` to your Dockerfile to mount all libraries/binaries in your docker container.

By doing so, the `libnvidia-encode` library will also be mounted, and so FFMPEG will be able to use NVENC codec.

Comment: How come your comment isn't the accept answer?
You just have to literally do this.

Comment: Does anyone know what are the actual capabilities needed for this? If I don't want to load "all"

Answer (score 1):

If you are using nvidia-docker for running the docker image then everything should be taken from the host.
You should have cuda installed on you host system first. "sudo apt-get install cuda" and then run the docker image.

You should also use the nvidia-cuda image instead of linux (in the dockerfile)